# Unable to access Tomcat 8 Host Manager (I can access Manager App just fine)

Tags: tomcat8

I am unable to access Host Manager after installing Tomcat 8 on my Ubuntu 16.04 server. I can access Manager App just fine.

I added `manager-gui` and `admin-gui` roles to my `tomcat-users.xml` file located in `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/` directory.

```
<tomcat-users . . .>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <user username="myusername" password="mypassword" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same issue. Solved it this way:

Find and edit your host-manager webapp context.xml file:

```
 $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml
```

Comment out the Valve that is restricting your access to only localhost:

```
    <Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
<!--
     <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
             allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
-->
```

Save and close the file.

Good practice would be to restart Tomcat, but I didn't need to, access was immediate.

Tomcat 8.5.29 on OEL 7.4, Java 1.8_162

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem as you.

This is how I resolved it:

conf/tomcat-users.xml (stays the same)

```
<tomcat-users>
   <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
   <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
   <user username="admin" password="password" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Under conf/Catalina/localhost I needed an additional file for each context:

manager.xml

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="^.*$" />
</Context>
```

host-manager.xml

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/host-manager">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="^.*$" />
</Context>
```

After that I was prompted for username and password and it worked.

I read some articles suggesting to edit the valves in /webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml and /webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml but I think the localhost one above takes precedence.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I didn't need to do any of that. After I shutdown Tomcat (`$CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh`) and started it back up (`$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh`), I was able to access Tomcat Virtual Host Manager. In order to gain access to Virtual Host Manager, I just needed `admin-gui` role and shutdown/startup of Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I was running Tomcat 9 on Windows 10.  Both Marc Hearling and user3559338 solutions work, but I'll add some additional insights.

The first unusually thing was that the solution didn't work if I included the docBase argument.  If I deleted that argument I was able to get Manager App and Server Status work.  However, host-manager did not work.  What I eventually discovered was the host-manager directory was missing from the webapps directory.  I downloaded the tomcat zip file and was able to restore the missing directory.  I don't know for sure why it was missing. I originally installed Tomcat using the windows installer rather than using the tomcat zip file. Maybe that installer is not installing the host-manager directory.  It's possible that I accidentally deleted that folder, but I kind of doubt that.  After I got Manager App, Server Status, and host manager working, I put the docBase argument back in the two xml context files, and this time they worked.  I then played around with docBase and noticed that, for example, you could still access the host manager even if you put in a bogus docBase address. That makes me wonder what the exact situation is when one needs to include the docBase parameter.  The only way I could get the docBase parameter to fail is if I removed one of the quotes.  That makes sense since that makes the xml invalid. The unfortunate thing is that Tomcat does not log an error for this kind of mistake.